# Unsure about InfoSphere 11.7 nulls handling

Tags: null, datastage, ibm-infosphere

At work I've come across with an old process written in InfoSphere 11.7, I'm trying to migrate it to another framework but no one seems to know how it works (including me, of course).

The ETL process takes as input a fixed length .txt UTF-8 file. File estructure is as follows:

```
300000007200_0000000000004 20230524123704000000  P4    0001000073873269002000005091662                                           0001000073875269002        8                                          1
700202909 2160000000005967 20230524041311000000  P1    000100005606358000700000236541000045097                      2502000501851        0001000066063680007        1000         000000237540000000    1
30000008810000000000003279 20230524041319000000  P2    00010000681349580050000366684071497  6204131926                         00000100006813496800464000000000000000036768100000                      1
```

At some point the program evaluates null values using the `IsNull` function at a certain position on each row like:

```
If IsNull(Substrings(Input.reg,1,1)) then " " else Substrings(Input.reg,1,1)
```

I'm familiar with null values in pandas, or SQL, but I'm not sure what is a null value in this context. From my understanding there will never be a null value, as there will always be a character (including spaces) at every position within the file.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dev searches for Substrings(Input.reg,1,1), which *in theory* can return null *despite the fact* that the input can't deliver something to get null. If the target column type is not nullable, you need to deliver an expression that returns a "not-null". Therefore they wrap the input like this or alternatively with the NullToValue() or NullToEmpty() function, so that the expression itself guarantees a non-nullable output.

Comment: If I got you right, is more of a "safety" measure rather than a expected situation, i.e. the `If` condition will always evaluate to `False`.

Comment: The if condition _should_ evaluate to false, but the program cannot expect the human to always deliver proper input. Therefore it could theoretically fail. But yes, you got me right.